# Adding transparency without losing the lighting to this shader

Tags: unity, shaders

How does one have transparency without losing the lighting in this shader? Seems when I enable pragma alpha, the lighting is lost

````
Shader "CrossSection/OnePlaneBSPT2" {
    Properties{
        _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _CrossColor("Cross Section Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Glossiness("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _PlaneNormal("PlaneNormal",Vector) = (0,1,0,0)
        _PlanePosition("PlanePosition",Vector) = (0,0,0,1)
        _StencilMask("Stencil Mask", Range(0, 255)) = 255
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        //LOD 200
        Stencil
        {
            Ref [_StencilMask]
            CompBack Always
            PassBack Replace

            CompFront Always
            PassFront Zero
        }
        Cull Back
            CGPROGRAM
            // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

            // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
#pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;

            float3 worldPos;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _CrossColor;
        fixed3 _PlaneNormal;
        fixed3 _PlanePosition;
        bool checkVisability(fixed3 worldPos)
        {
            float dotProd1 = dot(worldPos - _PlanePosition, _PlaneNormal);
            return dotProd1 > 0  ;
        }
        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            if (checkVisability(IN.worldPos))discard;
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;
            // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
        
            Cull Front
            CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf NoLighting  noambient alpha

        struct Input {
            half2 uv_MainTex;
            float3 worldPos;

        };
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;
        fixed4 _CrossColor;
        fixed3 _PlaneNormal;
        fixed3 _PlanePosition;
        bool checkVisability(fixed3 worldPos)
        {
            float dotProd1 = dot(worldPos - _PlanePosition, _PlaneNormal);
            return dotProd1 >0 ;
        }
        fixed4 LightingNoLighting(SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten)
        {
            fixed4 c;
            c.rgb = s.Albedo;
            c.a = 0; 
            return c;
        }

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
        {
            if (checkVisability(IN.worldPos))discard;
            o.Albedo = _CrossColor;
            o.Alpha=0;
        }
            ENDCG
        
    }
    //FallBack "Diffuse"
}


```
````

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [rendering queues](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) and [blending](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html)? Or, since you're using a Surface Shader, [the alpha parameters for the `#pragma surface` directive](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html)?

Comment: That was easier than expected though still not sure how to mix and match alpha so that shadows still show

Comment: Want to post an answer below, or edit your question to ask about your new topic?

Comment: updated the question!